# Vertical rule of column runs into text above it when using paracol

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, paracol

I use the `paracol` package to create bilingual booklets. Some instances of the columns are set such that the [vertical rule touches the text of the title immediately above the columns][1] set via that package. This isn't always the case, but it does happen enough that I would like to fix it.

I have attempted to provided an MWE (I can strip it down even more if needed.)

Edit **iow** I'd like to not mess with `smalltitle` because I use it elsewhere and don't want the added `vspace`. I could, I guess, make a macro that would expand to the suggested solution, but I was wondering if you can actually tinker with the rule itself or if it's a spacing issue.

```
%% to run Gregorio

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage[autocompile]{gregoriotex}%%a solution needs to be compatible with running Gregorio to make the chant scores.
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[english,ecclesiasticlatin.usej]{babel}
     \babelprovide[hyphenrules=latin]{ecclesiasticlatin}
     \usepackage{needspace}
     
     \NewDocumentCommand{\smalltitle}{m}{%
\needspace{5\baselineskip}%
\vspace{\baselineskip}%
 {\centering #1\par}%
}

 \setlength{\columnsep}{3pc}
\setlength\columnseprule{0.4pt}

\begin{document}

 \begin{paracol}{2}
        Lætámini in Dómino et exultáte justi.

 Et gloriámini ómnes récti córde.
           \switchcolumn
    \noindent    Be glad in the Lord, and rejoice, ye just.
         
\noindent   And glory, all ye right of heart.
    \end{paracol}

\smalltitle{Collect.}
   \begin{paracol}{2}
   Orémus.
   
\lettrine{B}{e}atórum Mártyrum tuórum Proti et Hyacínthi nos, Dómine, fóveat pretiósa conféssio: et pia júgiter intercéssio tueátur.
\switchcolumn
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\noindent Let us pray. O Lord, we beseech thee, that the feast of thy blessed Martyrs and Bishops Protus and Hyacinth may keep us, and their worshipful prayers commend us.
\end{otherlanguage}
    \end{paracol}
    
      \begin{paracol}{2}
   Justum dedúxit Dóminus per vias rectas.

 Et osténdi illi regnum Dei.
           \switchcolumn
 \noindent           The Lord guided the just in right paths.
                  
\noindent  And showed him the kingdom of God.
    \end{paracol}

\smalltitle{Collect.}
   \begin{paracol}{2}
   Orémus.
   
\lettrine{A}{d}ésto, Dómine, supplicatiónibus nostris, quas in beáti Nicolái Confessóris tui solemnitáte deférimus: ut, qui nostræ justítiæ fidúciam non habémus, ejus qui tibi plácuit, précibus adjuvémur.
Per Dóminum.
\switchcolumn
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\noindent Let us pray. O Lord, mercifully hear the supplications, which we offer unto thee on this solemn feast day of thy blessed Confessor, Nicholas, and forasmuch as we put no trust in our own righteousness, grant that we may be helpen by his prayers who walked with thee. Through Jesus Christ, thy Son our Lord, Who liveth and reigneth with thee, in the unity of the Holy Ghost, God, world without end.  Amen.
\end{otherlanguage}
    \end{paracol}



\end{document}





[1]: https://imgur.com/a/qMVscvl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add some space below the "small title".

[image: a]

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\smalltitle}{m}{%
    \needspace{5\baselineskip}%
    \vspace{\baselineskip}%
    {\centering #1\bigskip\par}% changed <<<<<<
}
```

Comment: OK, but I don't want that to change universally. I like the default space here [see this example.](https://imgur.com/a/3gV17zj)

What can I do as needed to fix the rule when this occurs (because it only occurs sometimes) and I don't use the paracol (or any other arrangement) every time that I have a "small title".